# Group AggregateResult by field on records

Tags: apex, aggregateresult

I am trying to get the number of zipcodes base on the 'type' field on the record.
So if there 2 record where the Type is 'Right' and the postal code is 12345, and a user creates another record where the Type is 'Right' and postal code is 12345, I want the name of the record to be R_12345_003
The issue is that if there are existing records with a postal codes with 12345 and a user creates a record say with the Type field Farthest' it will include all record with the zipcode and not just by the type. In my org I have record with 2 postal different postal and in the dev console I see 2 records so I think the query is correct.  But when I go to create the name of the record I am not just getting the postal code count based on the Type field, I am getting the count of all the postal codes.  I need to be able to get the count of zipcodes grouped by the type field on the record.
Thank you
P

```
if( Trigger.isInsert){
        List<String> zips = new List<String>();
         List<String> types = new List<String>();

        for (Site__c site :(List<Site__c >) trigger.New)
            {
                zips.add(site.Zip_Code__c);
                types.add(site.Site_Type__c);
            }

            List<AggregateResult> zipCodes = [SELECT count(Id) zipids, Site_Type__c types, Zip_Code__c zips 
            FROM Site__c where Zip_Code__c in : zips AND Site_Type__c in : types
            GROUP BY Zip_Code__c,Site_Type__c];
            
                for (Site__c newSite : (List<Site__c> ) trigger.New){

                    string fieldtype = newSite.Site_Type__c == 'Farthest' ? 'F' : 'R';
                    
                    Map<String,Integer> mapZips = new Map<String,Integer>();
                    Map<string,String> mapType = new Map<string,String>();

                        for(AggregateResult aggResult : zipCodes)
                            {
                                mapZips.put((String)aggResult.get('zips'), (Integer)aggResult.get('zipids'));
                                mapType.put((String)aggResult.get('types'),(String)aggResult.get('types'));
                            }
                                           
                        if(mapZips.size()>0){ 
                            for(AggregateResult result :zipCodes){
                                if(((string)result.get('types')) == 'Farthest' && ((integer)result.get('zipids')) > 0 ){
                                    string postal  = newSite.Zip_Code__c;
                                    integer siteNum = ((integer)result.get('zipids')) + 1;
                                    String stringNum = String.valueOf(siteNum).leftPad(3, '0');
                                    newSite.Name = fieldtype +'_'+ newSite.Zip_Code__c +'_'+ stringNum;  
                                    break;
                                }
                                if(((string)result.get('types')) == 'Right' && ((integer)result.get('zipids')) > 0){
                                    string postal  = newSite.Zip_Code__c;
                                    integer siteNum = ((integer)result.get('zipids')) + 1;
                                    String stringNum = String.valueOf(siteNum).leftPad(3, '0');
                                    newSite.Name = fieldtype +'_'+ newSite.Zip_Code__c +'_'+ stringNum;  
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                            else{
                                string postal  = newSite.Zip_Code__c;
                                integer siteNum = 1;
                                String stringNum = String.valueOf(siteNum).leftPad(3, '0');
                                newSite.Name = fieldtype +'_'+ newSite.Zip_Code__c +'_'+ stringNum; 
                                }   
                }
        
    }
```

Comment: You cannot aggregate the fields that are being used to group the query results. But, you have used `count(Site_Type__c) typeids` and also grouped by `Site_Type__c`, which should have thrown a error. Are you sure this code is working? Also, I feel that you may a written a overly complicated code for simple requirement. Fix the aggregate query and see if that resolves the problem. Otherwise, try improving the question with details of the requirement and some sample data.

Comment: You are correct on the query, I was trying different things since I was unable to get the zipcode count based on the Type field. Remove group by Site_Type. In the debug log I can see the different counts based on field type.  Just not able to assign it correctly when creating the record name.

Comment: I suggest you add some details about the requirement, along with some sample data, if you are still running into issues?